# importing the lines from the text file skipping certain rows up and down of the text file in python

Tags: python, eol

I am new in python and need to extract my swat model output stored in text file. I was successful to extract the lines of text file which I need but still consist of empty rows top and bottom of the output from the following code (modified example code in Stackoverflow).

```
path="D:/rough_swat/models/SWAT/TxtInOut/output.std"
    for outhru in glob.glob(path):
        with open(outhru,'r') as outhru:
    # Skips text before the beginning of the interesting block:
            for line in outhru:
                if line.strip() == 'AVE ANNUAL VALUES': #Or whatever test is needed
                    break
    # Reads text until the end of the block:
            for line in outhru:  # This keeps reading the file
                if line.strip() == 'AVE MONTHLY BASIN VALUES':
                    break
                print line  # Line is extracted (or block_of_lines.append(line), etc.)
```

This method gave some unwanted empty rows of the original file (attached to you)
My text file has altogether 1879 rows in which I am trying to read the lines from 940 to 1732 exactly without any empty line above and below.

After import interested text rows from the file I want to specify the column names for each column. The python always consider the column after every white space

```
.....
.... line of interest starts from below line relates to 790th line of my text file
HRU  SUB CPMN SOIL    AREAkm2     CN    AWCmm    USLE_LS   IRRmm AUTONkh 
1   1 FRSDForSoil .356E+00        66.19  325.40    6.45    0.00    0.00               
2   1 BERMSealedGr.180E-02        78.90    20.00    3.82   0.00   300.00      
....
.....
7   2 RYE FlatDryS.900E-02        72.12    359.50   2.76    0.00     85.28           
....
792 21 SOYBRicePadS.630E-02       75.45    123.00   1.69    0.00     0.00
```

line after above line is not necessary to import the line above relates to 1732 the line of my test file.

While assigning the column names by using `usecols` column numbers are not equal to each rows due to the space are not uniform in each rows mainly due to the 3rd column (mix of text and number are not uniform) now I would like to divide into 3 columns for this third column namely as CPNM SOL and Area.

I hope for any kind of suggestion.
and it would greatly help my research work.

Comment: Observation: Don't use the same variable `outhru` for both the file name and the file handle.

Comment: ok but still has problem to split the sub cpmn soi and arekm2 as individual column in this file